# vb.net application regular expression error

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am making a application in vb.net and on almost first release but when testing I found an expression error. I have set everything correctly in code so this should not be a problem and I imported it too but I still get the same error. Here is my code area that has error. All other information of my code is not needed.

My imports:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

The code where the error is. Remember the error is regular expression:

```
Private Sub ButtonNUS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNUS.Click
    If TextBoxNUsern.Text = "" Or TextBoxNEmail.Text = "" Or TextBoxNPass.Text = "" Or TextBoxNPhone.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please don't leave empty areas.")
    ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNUsern.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty spaces or special char is not allowed in username.")
    ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPass.Text, TextBoxNRPass.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty spaces is not allowed in password.")
    ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNEmail.Text, "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Email must be valid.")
    ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPhone.Text, "^\+[0-9()-+]+$") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Phone number must be valid.")
    ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNCity.Text, "^[A-Za-z ]+$") Then
        MessageBox.Show("City must be valid. OPTIONAL")
    ElseIf TextBoxNPass.Text <> TextBoxNRPass.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password dosen't match. Please try again.")
    Else
```

The error message is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$" to
>   type 'Integer' is not valid.

It says its a integer. I think but its set to string i am sure lets say this line

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNUsern.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$")
```

Its a string because i am checking it in textboxnusern.text right? So, what's the problem here?

Comment: put the hyphen present in this `[0-9()-+]+$` to the last inside the char class but it won't solves your problm.

Comment: You are using this method:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hx7a5y(v=vs.110).aspx  Adjust your parameters to match the method signature.

Comment: @Filburt: you are correct.  But I'm calling BS on the OP for providing incorrect information in the question.  Looks like DavidSdot got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling IsMatch method with false paramters

```
...
ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPass.Text, TextBoxNRPass.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$")
...
```

but this expects the following parameters ([from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Public Shared Function IsMatch ( _
    input As String, _
    pattern As String, _
    options As RegexOptions _
) As Boolean
```

Comment: ;) I'd like to make friends :) up one for you

Comment: Can you give me a example with using lets say this: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPass.Text, TextBoxNRPass.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$") i understand now where my problem is i just want a example

Comment: Make two checks or join join NPass text and nrpass text with a simple &

Comment: Ok i did that and now in my project j pass and pass repeat j say i have empty space any idea why?

Comment: wrong regex, isn't \s the paramter to check for whitespaces

Comment: What regex is for if it dosen't match? example thextboxnpass.text dosen't match with the regex then it will show a message.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your code:

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPass.Text, TextBoxNRPass.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$")`

Now look at the MSDN `IsMatch` declaration.

```
Public Shared Function IsMatch ( _
    input As String, _
    pattern As String, _
    options As RegexOptions _
) As Boolean
```

You're trying to cast your string pattern into a RegexOptions which is a bitwise enum.

Correction:

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNRPass.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$")`

Comment: You just ninja'ed me. ;)

Comment: No problem dawg maybe next time.

Comment: I cant mark 2 answers soo imagine you are marked too.

Comment: Please mark this as answer as JILIL answered first

Comment: No problem :) it's all good happy that you got your answer that's all it matters

Comment: Fair play @DavidSdot :) thank you